# Kafka Broker Administration - Log Cleanup Policy

Tags: apache-kafka, messagebroker

I can see that a relevant bug has been raised in [Kafka JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194). IN Summary, the broker cannot schedule a log cleanup because the relevant log files can neither be compacted nor renamed for deletion. But it doesn't look like it has been resolved. I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue, and any workaround (if exists)?

It seems like the log files are never closed until the cluster is fully (and gracefully) shut down. Could anyone please suggest a workaround?

My Cluster Information

1) 3 Brokers and 3 Zookeepers
2) Standard Dev setup on the same laptop
3) All the log files are going under common `/tmp` directory, but structured within different sub-directories

```
/temp/zookeeper
/temp/zookeeper2
/temp/zookeeper3
/temp/kafka-logs
/temp/kafka-logs2
/temp/kafka-logs3
```

My broker config (broker IDs and log file locations are correctly replaced per serverX.properties file)

```
# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=999999999

log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=2
log.retention.bytes=262144000
log.segment.bytes=262144000
log.roll.hours=1    
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
offsets.retention.minutes=60
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183
# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=30000
# Compression details
compression.type=gzip
# delete topic enable
delete.topic.enable=true
```

KR,

Comment: I haven't seen this happening my set up, every time i change the retention policy , broker schedules old log files for deletion and they are deleted subsequently.

Comment: @AmitKumar        Thanks for your comment. Do you mind sharing your configuration as well as the cluster setup information? I have updated the question with my current cluster information